# Problem on annotating curves on a spaghetti plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I tried to run a spaghetti plot inspired on this: https://python-graph-gallery.com/123-highlight-a-line-in-line-plot/

It runs but ruins the plot

The plot runs fine, it's just the anottations that doesn't work

```py
#This works fine
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
my_dpi=96
plt.figure(figsize=(480/my_dpi, 480/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
for column in MKT_DF_PVT.drop('Year', axis=1):
   plt.plot(MKT_DF_PVT['Year'], MKT_DF_PVT[column], marker='', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)
plt.xlim(2000,2016)

#This part doesn' work
num=0
for i in MKT_DF_PVT.values[len(MKT_DF_PVT.index)-1][1:]:
   num+=1
   name=list(MKT_DF_PVT)[num]
   plt.text(10.2, i, name, horizontalalignment='left', size='small', color='grey')
```

Maybe it has to do with variables types?

```py
print(MKT_DF_PVT.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 15 entries, 0 to 14
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Year    15 non-null int64
13.0    15 non-null float64
14.0    15 non-null float64
15.0    15 non-null float64
15.3    15 non-null float64
15.5    15 non-null float64
16.0    15 non-null float64
16.1    12 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(7), int64(1)
memory usage: 1.0 KB
None
```

Comment: Your x-limits are 2000-2016 but you place the annotation at x=10.2. You need to adjust either so that the labels are displayed on your axis/plot. For example: `plt.text(2000, i, name, ...)`

Comment: I thought that was the size of the text hahaha
Thank you!